# Formatting Currency in a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I currently have a lightning component that is displaying variables that hold currency values.

The issue I am having is that I would like to format the currency with commas *in the UK format* meaning $3250.00 displays **with commas** --> $3,250.00 (and all other subsequent commas).

I have attempted this solution, both using the js override format and the below example example without luck:

```
<aura:attribute name="myCurr" type="Decimal" default="50000"/>
<ui:outputCurrency aura:id="curr" value="{!v.myCurr}"/>
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is my sample code below:

```
<aura:attribute name="GrossRevenuevalue" type="currency" default="0.00" />

<div class="slds-truncate" style="currency" title="Gross Revenue value"> {!v.GrossRevenuevalue}
```

*Added under function*

```
var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
var curr  = cmp.find("curr");
curr.set("v.GrossRevenuevalue", '$#,###.00');
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to use **format** attribute of ui:outputCurrency.

your currency field will be like:

```
<aura:attribute name="GrossRevenuevalue" type="Decimal" default="3250.00" />
Your amount is : <ui:outputCurrency aura:id="curr" value="{!v.GrossRevenuevalue}" format="$##,##,###,###.00"/>
```

£ or $ depending on currency you wanna use.

[image]

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_outputCurrency.htm

Comment: I have added the following: with no luck: 

`<aura:attribute name="GrossRevenuevalue" type="Decimal" default="50000.00" />

<ui:outputCurrency aura:id="curr" value="{!v.GrossRevenuevalue}" format="$#,###.00'"/>`

Comment: edited answe added code screenshot.

Comment: When I enter this my $ value actually shows up blank now. I am not sure why. The code seems correct. I will keep trying and let you know if I am missing something obvious

Answer (score 1):

For me a hardcoded locale-specific format always seems odd. Some users might switch their locale to France or German for example  and it would be nice that the component supports that.

If you are showing an fieldvalue you could try lightning:outputField

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_outputField.htm

Answer (score 1):

"¤#,##0.00"
¤ represents the currency sign, which is replaced by the currency symbol.

please check with this link.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_locale_value_provider.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the format in ui:outputCurrency itself.