# How can use custom currency in a input field?

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputfield, currency

I'm using LWC, but I can't set custom currency in the lightning-input, using type number or currency.

I also try to use lightning-input-field of type currency, but I found in documentation:

> Displays an input field for entering monetary data. The user’s
>   Salesforce locale determines the currency symbol and separator
>   characters used to format the number. Specifying a different locale is
>   currently not supported for currency.

We have users with, for example, local with USD but they can create Quotes in different currencies.

We need code something like that:

```
    <lightning-input type="number"
                 label="Price"
                 value="12345"
                 formatter="currency"
                 currencyIsoCode="EUR">
    </lightning-input>
```

Last line: `currencyIsoCode="EUR"` it's what I need to set.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the same problem exists in [aura](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228840/how-to-set-currency-code-to-lightninginput-type-number-formatter-currency), but the workaround is to use [ui:inputcurrency](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/215548/19118) . LWC does not have `ui-inputcurrency` equivalent yet and thus you have to build it yourself.

You can use SLDS classes to give lightning look, you can refer my sample:

```
<template>

<div class="slds-form-element">
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1" id="fixed-text-label">Price</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-fixed-addon">
    <span class="slds-form-element__addon" id="fixed-text-addon-pre">£</span>
    <input type="number" id="text-input-id-1" placeholder="2000" aria-labelledby="fixed-text-label fixed-text-addon-pre fixed-text-addon-post" class="slds-input" />
    <span class="slds-form-element__addon" id="fixed-text-addon-post">euro</span>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/jee6KjW0-/1/edit

Comment: Please note that the ui: components will be being deprecated as of the winter release if I correctly understood information given during the Salesforce Partner Forum London developer track sessions.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @PhilW

Comment: Thank you @PranayJaiswal
I had think about this solution, but I wanted to check if another one exists.I think I'll have to implement that.

Answer (score -1):

Lightning-input now supports FORMATTER attribute to allow CURRENCY and others like (decimal, percent, percent-fixed)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification