# Text Field Not Formatted in Currency When Selecting Currency Symbol from Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, picklist, html, currency

I've been repeatedly modifying a Salesforce LWC page which aims to format a text field into a currency format (with corresponding currency symbols, commas, and decimals). Displayed currency symbol depends on the selected value from `Currency__c` field.

Since I wanted to format the inputted text value when user leaves that input field, I used javascript's `onblur` event.

But upon leaving the input field, a Lightning error occurs, like the following:

[image]

Also, I checked the browser's console log, and it displays the value inputted from the text field. I am not sure what is wrong with my page. I even checked some tutorials if I got the correct event, and looks like `onblur` fits my requirement.

Meanwhile, below are the latest codes:

**customDropDownLWC.js**

```
//portion of js file

@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: CUSTOM_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId'})
currencyPicklistValues({error, data}) {
    if(data) {
        this.error = null;
    
        let currencyOptions = [{label:'--None--', value:'--None--'}];
   
   
        data.picklistFieldValues.Currency__c.values.forEach(key => {
            currencyOptions.push({
                label : key.label,
                value: key.value
            })
        });

        this.currencyValues = currencyOptions;

    }

    else if(error) {
        this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
    }
}


handleCurrencyDropDownChange(event) {

    this.custObj.Currency__c = event.target.value;
    this.selectedCurrency = this.custObj.Currency__c;

}

handleTextFieldChange(event) {

    this.custObj.Text_Field__c = event.target.value;
    const currencySelected = this.custObj.Currency__c; 
    console.log('Currency Selected' + currencySelected);

    if(currencySelected === '$') {

        let formattedString;

        console.log('Text Field' + this.custObj.Text_Field__c);

        let valueInt = parseInt(this.custObj.Text_Field__c, 10);

        formattedString = '$' + valueInt.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$&,");
            
        console.log('Formatted Text Field' + formattedString);
            
    }

    //same goes with other currency symbols....

}
```

**customDropDownLWC.html**

```
<!--portion of html template-->

<lightning-combobox label="Currency" 
    name="Currency" 
    onchange={handleCurrencyDropDownChange} 
    options={currencyValues} 
    placeholder="--None--" 
    value={custObj.Currency__c}>
</lightning-combobox>

<lightning-input label="Text Field"
    type="text"
    value={formattedString}
    onblur={handleTextFieldChange}>
</lightning-input>
```

Comment: Try [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264575/how-can-use-custom-currency-in-a-input-field), I think it is better not to change the original value.

Comment: What do you mean not to change the original value?

Comment: You are replacing the value in the input box on blur

Comment: I already used `custObj.Text_Field__c` in the input box on blur, but same error occurs.

Comment: have you tried adding console logs? the primary reason for this error is the null pointer.

Comment: yes, I checked my browser's console logs and it displays the following result: `Formatted Text Field500`. It catches the original text value inputted, not the formatted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toFixed()` works only on the number, the `Text_Field__c` is of type text. You need to convert that to a number first. Use `parseFloat()`.

Also, use `let` instead of `var` to create a block-scoped variable.

I have created a [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/UnfKQayII/8/edit).

Comment: Regarding the conversion, I converted `Text_Field__c` to number using `parseInt` (for now) before using it with `toFixed()`. Also used `let` instead of `var`. But there's a weird thing going on, when I checked the console log, it displays the expected format `Formatted Text Field$500.00` but when I check the UI and leave the input field, it just displays `500`. I even tried using either `formattedString` or `custObj.Text_Field__c` for the input field value . but nothing works.

Comment: As for the input field type, I use `text` as I also needed to append the currency symbol I selected from the dropdown list. Number type does the trick for the comma, but I think it won't work if I will add the currency symbol.

Comment: I modified my codes, please check.

Comment: Ohh yeah, you can use type text then.. I didn't realize that you can't show symbol in number type input, ihave updated my answer

Comment: I visited your playground, and I noticed that we have same result. Correct result on the console log but incorrect display on the UI. I even tried both `onchange` and `oninput` for the event, but nothing makes the selected picklist value to be displayed on the text field before record insert.

Comment: Lightning error also has disappeared. Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: @Ertyq check updated playground

Comment: I followed your approach from your playground, and finally, after multiple modifications, it works!! Thank you very much for all your help and effort :))